# Who likes Actress E?

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

This is a logical puzzle that I found, but I can't for the life of me figure out who likes Actress E and hence I'm stuck. The question is as follows :

At a movie theatre six people are  randomly chosen to take part in a survey. Out of the 6 people 4 are working professionals and 2 are college students.
These six people each live in 4 different parts of the city namely Area P, Area Q, Area R and  Area S. In the survey each person is asked two questions

> Question 1 - What type of movies do they like?  Each  person answered a different type of movie out of Cartoons, Science Fiction, Comedies, Dramas, Documentaries and Tragedies.
>
> Question 2 - Who is their favourite actress?  Again  each person  answered a different actress namely A, B, C, D, E or F.
> The following information is provided

- None of the working professionals like Science Fiction or Tragedies.
- Only two persons live in Area Q and one of them  likes Cartoons and the other likes Tragedies
- One of the persons who lives in  Area  R likes Documentaries
- One of the persons who lives in Area S likes Dramas
- The college students live in Area Q and Area P
- The person whose favourite actress is C does not like Dramas
- The person whose favourite actress is E does not like Cartoons
- Two working professionals who are the only people living in their respective areas have their favourite actresses as B and C .

Comment: You have 2 people in Q, and the implication of at least 2 in R and S. You have at least 1 in P, so that makes 7 areas.

Comment: @DrXorile R and S don't have to have more than one, even if the wording suggests it.

Comment: I think there is not enough information to solve this.

Comment: Unless there's some fault in my logic, either the two college student, or the person who likes comedy likes actress E

Comment: The person who likes comedy likes either B or C.

Comment: @DrXorile that's not possible, we know the two students live in area Q and P, so from the second last hint, it is implied that only one working professional live in area R and one in area S, and one of them like B, and one of them like C. in particular. the working professional living in R likes documentary and C, and working professional living in S likes drama and B

Comment: Oh, I read the last clue differently, but your interpretation makes more sense

Comment: err I meant last clue, since the last line is not a clue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not enough information to determine which person chose Actress E.

Suppose we have a situation that satisfies all of the statements. One person chose A, one chose D and one person chose F. Out of these three people, at most one likes cartoons. Then we can switch E with one of the other two, producing another situation that satisfies all of the statements.

---

The information we can deduce is as follows:

> A professional, who likes documentaries and chose Actress C, lives alone in area R.
> A professional, who likes dramas and chose Actress B, lives alone in area S.
> A professional, who likes cartoons and did not choose Actress E, lives in area Q.
> A student, who likes tragedies, lives in area Q.
> A professional, who likes comedies, lives in area P.
> A student, who likes science fiction, lives in area P.

Any one of the last three people in that list could have chosen E.

Comment: This is the same conclusion I got

Comment: It was taken from an example question paper for an entrance examination  of a College. Idk, if it's complete or not but your answers does make a lot more sense to me. Thank you for your times and everyone who tried it out.

Answer (score 0):

WP1 lives is P, likes Comedy and actress A, D, E, or F

WP2 lives in S, likes Drama and likes B

WP3 lives in R, likes Documentaries and C

WP4 lives in Q, likes Cartoons and likes A, D or F

C1 lives in P, likes SF and doesn't like B or C

C2 lives in Q, likes Tragedies and doesn't like B or C.